# Clang recursive include path

Tags: linux, windows, compiler-errors, clang

I have a problem when including dependency folder as this isn't looking for headers recursively.

**FOLDER STRUCTURE:**

```
- main.cpp
- dependency
  - sub1
    - header1.h
  - sub2
    - header2.h
  - root-header.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "root-header.h"
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"

int main() {

}
```

**Command:**

```
clang main.cpp -I"dependency"
```

**Error:**

```
fatal error: 'header1.h' file not found
```

*The command only detects header.h inside dependency folder to one level, how to make the **clang** to recursively lookup for all headers inside dependency folder. Is there any compiler arguments to be added?*

**Thanks**

Comment: Are there other compilers that do this? Recursively looking for headers will cause issues. I don't think it's expected.

Answer (score 3):

The ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard in section §6.10.2 explains the expected behavior of clang and other compilers:

> `# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the < and > delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.

You can modify the defined places by adding additional with the `-I` option, but a compiler should not search sub-directories.

You can work around this limitation in the spec by using `make` to compile a list of additional `-I` locations to add to you `clang` command. This is covered in @DanBonachea answer.

Instead, I'd advise you to change the includes to be compliant to the specification:

```
#include "sub1/header1.h"
#include "sub2/header2.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

The conventional solutions are one of the following:

### 1. Change the include directives in the source code

This solution compiles with `clang++ -Idependency main.cpp` but modifies `#include` directives to include headers by subdirectory, eg:

```
#include "sub1/header1.h"
#include "sub2/header2.h"
```

This is obviously a modification to the code, so usually only makes sense if `sub1` and `sub2` are meaningful within the larger structure of the software (e.g. package names that are always the same). Or...

### 2. Use shell tools to traverse the directory and build the include path

This solution uses `find` to inject subdirectories on the include path, eg:

```
$ clang++ `find ./dependency -type d -exec echo -I'{}' \;` main.cpp
```

which scans to identify the subdirectories and adds them to the preprocessor include path.

### Discussion

Both of these approaches should work with few changes with basically any C/C++ compiler on UNIX (incl Linux, macOS, WSL, etc).

Note the second approach above will involve some additional filesystem churn on every compilation, which might be noticeable if the number of subdirectories is very large. To be fair this cost is fundamental to that use case, and even if built-in support for recursive include existed in the compiler frontend, it would still need to perform a similarly expensive recursive directory traversal on every compilation to find all the files.

### 3. Amortize directory traversal

However we can improve upon the second solution if we assume all the headers that will be included from this directory structure have unique names. This is a reasonable assumption, because otherwise the unqualified `#include` directives inside the source files will be ambiguous, leading to orthogonal problems. With this assumption in hand, we can create a cache to amortize the cost of the dependency directory traversal as follows:

```bash
$ mkdir allheaders ; cd allheaders
$ find ../dependency -type f -exec ln -s '{}' . \;
```

Then compilation simply becomes:

```bash
$ clang++ -Iallheaders main.cpp
```

Or, if you additionally want to support a mix of option 1 and option 3 `#include` directives, then:

```bash
$ clang++ -Idependency -Iallheaders main.cpp
```

This approach could greatly accelerate compilation, because the preprocessor only needs to open one user directory and open the files by basename. The fact that the directory may contain a large number of headers (with some fraction potentially unused) should not significantly degrade performance, thanks to how filesystems work.

If we further assume the file names in the `dependency` directory change infrequently or never, then we only need to execute the directory traversal step once, and can amortize that cost against repeated compilation using the `allheaders` cache directory.

Comment: Aren't there any compiler flags? Because in my case the dependency folder is more ~1k and the files to be compiled is massive ~15k. It will take a lot more time to include each folder for each compilation.

Comment: @Veno AFAIK clang has no *built-in* feature to recursively include a directory tree. However even if it did, it would likely need to be implemented using a recursive directory search on every compilation, which would similarly impact each compilation time. I've added a third idea to my answer to amortize this cost, which could improve on performance for your use case.

Comment: @Veno I've edited to add a refinement to the third solution to handle that case

Comment: This isn't a permanent solution. It won't include all cases.

Comment: @Veno Clarify "It won't include all cases"? Which of the three options in this answer are you referring to and why?